# Updating position index in xml after select

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following xml that when selected in groups of at most three needs to have their index value modified to reflect its new position in the returned xml. I have wrote out what result I need at the bottom of this post.

```
<root>
  <document>
    <index>1</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>2</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>3</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>4</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>5</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>6</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>7</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>8</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>9</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>10</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
</root>
```

After extracting by a maximum of groups of three.

```
<root>
  <document>
    <index>1</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>2</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>3</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
</root

<root>
  <document>
    <index>1</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>2</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>3</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
</root

<root>
  <document>
    <index>1</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>2</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
  <document>
    <index>3</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
</root

<root>
  <document>
    <index>1</index>
    <text>stuff</text>
  </document>
</root
```

Comment: In the resulting XML will you have a root node that contains all the <root> elements?

Comment: No. Each group is from a distinct select performed against the original xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the XML returned by your query in a variable and update the index value.

```
set @XMLTarget.modify('replace value of (/root/document/index/text())[1] with 1')
set @XMLTarget.modify('replace value of (/root/document/index/text())[2] with 2')
set @XMLTarget.modify('replace value of (/root/document/index/text())[3] with 3')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20060)